# Assigning a timestamp value to a series with pandas creates an int instead

Tags: python, pandas

In Python, Pandas:

```
g = pd.Series(dict(a = 5, b =datetime(2018, 1,1)))
g['datetime'] = pd.Timestamp('2018-01-02')
```

`g` returns:

```
a                             5
b           2018-01-01 00:00:00
datetime    1514851200000000000
dtype: object
```

Anyone has an idea why the timestamp is converted to its int value here, and how to avoid the problem and properly attach a timestamp to the Series?

Comment: If you repeat `g['datetime'] = pd.Timestamp('2018-01-02')` it will properly create the value as a `Timestamp`, so it appears to be an issue when it initially adds the index to the Series.

Comment: @ALollz I confirmed that to be True.  I initialized `'datetime'` the index value with and int then subsequently `g['datetime'] = pd.Timestamp('2018-01-02')` and it worked fine.

Comment: Thx guys, will post an issue on the pandas github

Comment: I think it makes sense: 5 is not a datetime object, so pandas is parsing the data and find that you have both a number and a datetime object, and it parses both as 'object' string, because the dtype needs to be consistent across all data in the Series. The string representation of a datetime is the date string, not timestamp. When you then add to it, you can modify the dtype of a cell

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @MrE, as he says:

> I think it makes sense: 5 is not a datetime object, so pandas is parsing the data and find that you have both a number and a datetime object, and it parses both as 'object' string, because the dtype needs to be consistent across all data in the Series. The string representation of a datetime is the date string, not timestamp. When you then add to it, you can modify the dtype of a cell

I really agree, it has to find a `dtype` and found `int`, if you drop the `'a'` index, it will work (this is basically checking if the above is true or not):

```
g = pd.Series(dict(b =datetime(2018, 1,1)))
g['datetime'] = pd.Timestamp('2018-01-02')
print(g)
```

Output:

```
b          2018-01-01
datetime   2018-01-02
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

So it is true.

### To solve the issue:

Simply add an extra line at the end:

```
g['datetime']=pd.to_datetime(g['datetime'])
```

And now:

```
print(g)
```

Is:

```
a                             5
b           2018-01-01 00:00:00
datetime    2018-01-02 00:00:00
dtype: object
```